# Encryption and deleted data

Tags: factory-reset, encryption, privacy, samsung-galaxy-s-8

I have a galaxy S8 using "default password" meaning no startup password or secure start up.
The device is still encrypted by default so all data should not be recoverable after a factory reset as the old encryption key is deleted and a new one is generated on reboot. This is to my limited understanding. Is this right?

Now what about data that was "deleted" before the factory reset like photos or unwanted files that were "deleted" and then the device was reset? Is any of that info recoverable?

Comment: why should deleted file easier to recover than (unrecoverable) existing file? encrypted is encrypted no matter what kind of file it was

Comment: So deleted files are still encrypted and unrecoverable after a factory reset? Also, do I have the first part right about default encryption despite no password?

Comment: yes. the whole partition is encrypted, there is nothing left. not even a file system. the passphrase is *"default_password"* so there actually **is** a password. read more about [FDE](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/full-disk#storing_the_encrypted_key) key derivation [here](https://soonerorlater.hu/download/They_thinked_differently_DerbyCon2013.pdf)