# How safe is factory reset if I didn't have a pin or password?

Tags: factory-reset, encryption, privacy

Some months ago I had to return a phone to the store and all I did was factory reset to erase everything (I did it two times too). Now I'm getting paranoid about how safe my information is and if it's possible to recover it. I've heard that modern android phones have an automatic encryption system tied to the pin or password. The thing is that I think I didn't have one for the phone and I'm wondering if my information is still safe or it can be recovered easily

Comment: The comments of this question are answering your question: [Encryption and deleted data](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/246931/2241)

Answer (score 0):

While I am not a security expert, the way I understand it is that there is still full disk encryption, even without a pin/password. (The world being the way it is, there may always be some way discovered that allows a break in, but after a factory reset, this process should not be easy.)

**TL;DR:** using the factory reset option is still the best way to keep your data safe.

As noted in the comments on this question and the [linked question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/246931/364149), the following article has some helpful information on this:

https://source.android.com/docs/security/features/encryption/full-disk